# Optimized Query Execution Time

Tags: performance, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

My Query is

```
SELECT unnest(array [repgroupname,repgroupname||'-' 
||masteritemname,repgroupname||'-' ||masteritemname||'-'||itemname]) AS grp
    ,unnest(array [repgroupname,masteritemname,itemname]) AS disp
    ,groupname1
    ,groupname2
    ,groupname3
    ,sum(qty) AS qty
    ,sum(freeqty) AS freeqty
    ,sum(altqty) AS altqty
    ,sum(discount) AS discount
    ,sum(amount) AS amount
    ,sum(stockvalue) AS stockvalue
    ,sum(itemprofit) AS itemprofit
FROM (
    SELECT repgroupname
        ,masteritemname
        ,itemname
        ,groupname1
        ,groupname2
        ,groupname3
        ,units
        ,unit1
        ,unit2
        ,altunits
        ,altunit1
        ,altunit2
        ,sum(s2.totalqty) AS qty
        ,sum(s2.totalfreeqty) AS freeqty
        ,sum(s2.totalaltqty) AS altqty
        ,sum(s2.totaltradis + s2.totaladnldis) AS discount
        ,sum(amount) AS amount
        ,sum(itemstockvalue) AS stockvalue
        ,sum(itemprofit1) AS itemprofit
    FROM sales1 s1
    INNER JOIN sales2 s2 ON s1.txno = s2.txno
    INNER JOIN items i ON i.itemno = s2.itemno
    GROUP BY repgroupname
        ,masteritemname
        ,itemname
        ,groupname1
        ,groupname2
        ,groupname3
        ,units
        ,unit1
        ,unit2
        ,altunits
        ,altunit1
        ,altunit2
    ORDER BY itemname
    ) AS tt
GROUP BY grp
    ,disp
    ,groupname1
    ,groupname2
    ,groupname3
```

Here

```
Sales1 table have 144513 Records
Sales2 Table have 438915 Records
items Table have 78512 Records
```

This Query take 6 seconds to produce result.

How to Optimize this query?

am using postgresql **9.3**

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: Provide `EXPLAIN ANALYZE <<your-query>>;` output.

Answer (score 0):

That is a truly horrible query.

You should start by losing the ORDER BY in the sub-select - the ordering is discarded by the outer query.

Beyond that, ask yourself why you need to look to see a summary of every songle row in th DBMS - does this serve any useful purpose (if the query is returning more than 20 rows, then the answer is no).

You might be able to make it go faster by ensuring that the foreign keys in the tables are indexed (indexes are THE most important bit of information to look at whenever you're talking about performance and you've told us nothing about them).

Maintaining the query as a regular snapshot will mitigate the performance impact.